# Searching for folders in C++

Tags: c++, file, search, directory

I am somewhat of a beginner to programming, I need help on a task to write a script that takes an input of a number of strings that are folders,  search the list of folders against the existing folders in the current location in cmd, it shows which one exists, which one doesn't exist. out of the ones that exist, it shows how many files there are inside.

For example, im in Desktop directory(say it contains a, bb, c), i type in a, b, aa, bb, it will search a, b, aa, bb against all the folder names in the current directory, then it outputs a, bb, c exists, aa, b don't exist. Then it shows how many files are inside a, bb, c.

I am short of time, any immediate help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Tip: You didn't specify an operating system.

Comment: `boost::filesystem` probably has something great for this. I'm not familiar enough with boost to lead you any more than that off the top of my head.

Comment: Sorry guys, its for windows 7 64 bit with Visual studio 2005 environment variable

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Boost.Filesystem](http://boost.org/libs/filesystem), which is a cross-platform libary abstracting filesystem operations such as querying for files properties, creating, copying and moving files. As a bonus, it is proposed for standardisation in a future version of the C++ ISO standard.

As a starting point, here is an example that will process every file in a given directory.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        boost::filesystem::path directory(argv[1]);

        if (boost::filesystem::exists(directory) && boost::filesystem::is_directory(directory))
        {
            boost::filesystem::directory_iterator begin(directory);
            boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end;

            while(begin != end)
            {
                std::cout << *begin << " ";
                ++begin;
            }   
            std::cout << "\n";
        }   
    }
}
```

It show you that you can:

- Iterate over every file in a directory
- Query if a given path exist
- Query if a given path point to a directory

Other function you could be interested in:

- Query for the current working directory ([`boost::filesystem::current_path()`](http://boost.org/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path))

Answer (score 0):

There are some great libraries that make this very painless and cross platform.

Qt and Boost are some of the most well known.

Here are links to the documentation for the relevant classes that would do this for you:

[Boost `Filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) and [Qt `QDir`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qdir.html).

I prefer Qt, because the documentation has been very unified for a long time and I also really like the IDE.